# Pass junit testname into guice injected objects

Tags: java, junit4, guice, saucelabs

I am writing a webDriver end to end test framework using junit 4 and guice for injection.

I want to pass the test name into my driverFactory so that I can use it to name the test properly in Saucelabs:
in my AbstractTest (used by currently all tests) I use

```
    @Rule
    public TestName name = new TestName();
```

and

```
    @Before
    public void before() {
    System.setProperty("testName", name.getMethodName());
    // This is unfortunately, the only way I have managed to make the test name available to the configuration factory
    Guice.createInjector(new TestModule()).injectMembers(this);
```

I can then retrieve this value from inside my TestModule constructor using

```
    testConfig.setTestName(System.getProperty("testName"));
```

I tried many other approaches to make my testName available to the TestModule where I can make it available to other classes. The all fall over for basically the same reason:

I can set a field in the test module created here, but the first time that a TestModule is injected, it is second new instance and it is this second instance that is now injected without the correct field value.

I would prefer another strategy than setting a System property but I failed hopelessly. Can anyone suggest anything better?

(If its relevant I am running my tests in parallel from Gradle)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't pass it into your TestModule constructor?

Comment: I did try that, but I couldn't make it work. I think it was causing a circular reference problem when trying to inject a new TestModule

Comment: But each test should have had its own `TestModule`, right? What do you mean by "inject a new TestModule"?

Comment: I am using  single TestModule class at present as so far I am not requiring different bindings

Comment: I guess is the issue that I am trying to pass a runtime value from my test code to be accessible from my main code.

Comment: The tests in this case are not testing the main source code but controlling the main code to test an application on a different server using Saucelabs.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue of I don't know enough about Saucelabs to help. Would you be able to post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks for the help @DanielBickler You have helped me to understand what is going on a little better. My attempt to generate a MVCE wasn't very small but has given me some ideas to work on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`BoundFieldModule`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/testing/fieldbinder/BoundFieldModule.html) for this:

```
@Rule @Bind
public final TestName name = new TestName();


@Before
public void injectMembers() {
  Guice.createInjector(
      BoundFieldModule.of(this);
      new TestModule())
      .injectMembers(this);
}
```